# Recipe database design advice

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a problem designing my database.
I have to make a table witch contains let's say a Recipe.
I have tables that contain let's say: Spices, Meats, Veggies.

Okay now I need to get data from the Spices, Meats, Veggies and create a recipe in the Recipes table. My question is how to map all of these into the recipes considering that one recipe can have more veggies, more types of meet and more spices.

Thanks.

Comment: No this was not homework, just a personal project that I wanted some advice on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meat, vegetables and spices are **ingredients**, `IngredientType` (M,V,S) is used to identify each group.

[image]

If for some reason you feel that each ingredient needs its own table because they have different columns, then use this model. Keep all common columns in the `Ingredient` table.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your solution...another question tho... if I implement the design in which I separate the ingredients in it's own table how can I add multiple translations to it? What approach do you suggest?

Comment: What is the meaning of the the half moon in with the 'X' in it that connects Ingredient and IngredientType?

Comment: @Hexatonic, subtype discriminator -- mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me you are talking about a n-m relationship :

- a Recipe can have many Spices / Meats
  / Veggies
- Each one of Spices / Meats / Veggies
  can be tied to many Recipe.

The way you usually store this in a database is with an association table between Recipe and, for example, Veggies.

```
Recipe <----> RecipeVeggies <----> Veggies
```

Recipe and Veggies must each have an unique primary key (id) and the table RecipeVeggies store both primary keys to create an association between the two.

Here's a little structure example :

```
Recipe : id, name, description
Veggies : id, name
RecipeVeggies : recipe_id, veggies_id
```

The RecipeVeggies table create store the relation between a Recipe and a Veggie.

You must create similar tables for Spices and Meats.

I hope I'm clear, otherwise feel free to ask more questions and I'll improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do.

I would use inheritance mapping, every ORM has it, and almost every web language has it as well (php has doctrine, java and .net have Hibernate etc).

As the example in this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html) shows, you have a table at the top of your hierarchy, for your system, I would call it Ingredient, then have veggie/meat/spices as sub tables.  Then I would make a table called Recipe, and it would have a one to many relationship with the ingredient table.

I hope you are using an ORM for this,it will save you a TON of time and will result in a lot less bugs.

Thank you for the interesting question, its nice having a more subjective design type question to get the creative juices flowing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way.. in the recipe table list down the details of the recipe name (say  x) which is repeated for each of the content of the recipe item, then you could create another table with the recipe item name and number to it.. use this number in the original table.. in short normalize the recipe table.. you can do it further for each of the ingredient.

Answer (score 0):

You have a so called `n:m` Relationship between recipes and ingredients. The usual method to resolve this in a relational database is to introduce a mapping table.

Say each of your recipes has an id (`RecipeID`) and each ingredient also has an id (`IngredientID`). Then you create a new table which contains both a `RecipeID` column and an `IngredientID` column. Each record in this table maps an ingredient to a recipe and vice versa.

Such a table is also handy if you want to qualify the relationship further. For example you could add another column to the mapping table containing a description of how much of the ingredient would be needed for the recipe.